# sending large amount of information via android email client

Tags: android, email

I am writing an application that on error sends some information to support using android internal mail client.

I have noted that the message is trimmed to 9000 characters (including spaces).

how can I send larger amount of information?

I am thinking about exporting the information to a fie on SD card and then send it as attachment can anyone tell me how to do this?

thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save it to storage and then attach it. There's an example here:
[How to send/open email attachments from android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033818/how-to-send-open-email-attachments-from-android-app)