# Send Email with pdf file as attachment in rhomobile

Tags: ruby, email, pdf, email-attachments, rhomobile

I want to send email using mailto tag with a single pdf file as attachment.
mailto tag opens the mail window with passed arguments like to and subject using:

```
<a href="mailto:<%=@user.mgremail%>?subject=Expense Report&attachment='<%=fileNameW%>'">Mail to Manager</a>
```

But, attachments as a parameter isnt working.
Please suggest how to send pdf attachment in rhomobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to add the physical path to the PDF file for it to work (otherwise it may not know where the file is). [This post](http://forums.devshed.com/beginner-programming-16/using-mailto-with-an-attachment-66699.html) on a forum says as follows:

> The only problem is that this "mailto" command executes on the
>   client machine, therefore it tries to locate the attachment file by
>   a physical path, and not by a virtual path.
>
> That is,
>
> 1. Using mailto:iudith.m@zim.co.il?subject=my report&body=see attachment&attachment="\myhost\myfolder\myfile.lis"
>
>    > works ok, but only for local users (those connected to the same
>    >     network as the "myhost" machine).
> 2. Using mailto:iudith.m@zim.co.il?subject=my report&body=see attachment&attachment="http://myhost:myport/my_location_virtual_path/myfile.lis"
>
>    > > does not work, it does not recognize such a syntax as valid for
>    > >       the attachment file.

In your case you would properbly need to look at [this part](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#file-system-access) of the Rhomobile docs (on file system access) to get the right path to your file.

**EDIT:**

From you comment I can see that you are trying to make it work on iOS (due to the iOS specific path).

In [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rhomobile/EMVzy-Jj5xI) (from Rhomobile's Google Group) it is explained that mailto doesn't support attachments on iOS. It says as follows:

> Don't know about other platforms, but you cannot do this on iOS. mailto: does not support attachments on iOS.
>
> You can do it using a native API, MFMailComposeViewController.
>
> This is a complete controller with UI, so you would have to write a Native View Extension to use it:
>
> http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#native-view-extensions

**EDIT 2:**

I've looked around and it seems that mailto doesn't support attachments on Android either. This is because Android supports the RFC 2368 mailto protocol, which doesn't include attachments. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/MailTo.html) is a reference to the Android mailto url parser.

I would suggest that you do as suggested for iOS, write a native extension. I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033818/how-to-send-open-email-attachments-from-android-app) would be relevant for you.

Comment: I am giving the complete path but it isnt working. Code is like:  <%  fileNameW = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication::get_user_path(), 'demo.pdf')%>
   <a href="mailto:<%=@user.mgremail%>?subject=Expense Report&attachment='<%=fileNameW%>'">Mail to Manager</a>

Comment: Couldn't figure out what made you think i am doing this for ios. I am developing an Android app on Rhomobile.

Comment: As far as I can see, the 'Rho::RhoApplication::get_user_path' is iOS specific. It is only mentioned under "Rhodes client file system structure on iOS platform" in the Rhodes documentation. Maybe that is your problem ?

Comment: It is working for me at other places as well. Still i tried giving the static path as well but neither it returns any error nor it recognizes the attachment. Do you know any other alternative for this?